# Modular arithmetic - Suggestions to begin

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, soft-question, modular-arithmetic

I've always wanted to start studying modular arithmetic to try to solve problems like:

$$\text{find } n \in \mathbb{N} : 4n^2 \equiv 1 ~(\text{mod }{10^4})$$

I have a good basis in mathematical analysis and logic. Where can I start to study modular arithmetic?

I prefer some internet tutorial, but also a book is good.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Gauss, *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae*, preferrably in the Latin original.

Comment: A University's lecture notes on Elementary Number Theory would probably be a good place to start. I can give you the lecture notes that I use for my ENT module (at KCL) but even something like openlearn offer good course material

Comment: Gauss's DA to "begin" with modular arithmetic, @TooOldForMath ? Oh, my...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does not exist such n, where $ n \in \mathbb{N} $.

$$4n^2 = 10^4 k + 1$$

$4n^2$ is even, but $10^4 k + 1$ is odd.